# How do I check if a value exists in earlier values in the same column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I'd like to check if a value appeared in a given column for any date prior to the date referenced in the current row. I'll share my data and what I tried.

Here is my data frame.

```
stocks <- tibble(
  time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X = round(rnorm(10, 20, 1)),
  Y = round(rnorm(10, 20, 2)),
  Z = round(rnorm(10, 20, 4))
)
```

Just for starters, I wanted to see if I could make a relative reference and pull all the values prior to the given date.

```
stocks %>% 
  mutate(in_prev = paste0(stocks[stocks$time < time, ]$X, collapse = "/"))
```

The result I would like to get would be

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   time           X     Y     Z in_prev
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
 1 2009-01-01    20    19    24 ""     
 2 2009-01-02    22    22    25 "20"     
 3 2009-01-03    21    19    17 "20/22"     
 4 2009-01-04    20    16    20 "20/22/21"
```

Instead, I get a dataframe where the `in_prev` col is empty.

I'd like to turn this into a query to check whether the value for X in a given row appeared in the X column for any earlier dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
stocks <- tibble(time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
                 X = round(rnorm(10, 20, 1)),
                 Y = round(rnorm(10, 20, 2)),
                 Z = round(rnorm(10, 20, 4)))

stocks %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(in_prevX = paste0(unique(stocks[stocks$time < time, ]$X), collapse = "/"))

#> Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    time           X     Y     Z in_prevX
#>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
#>  1 2009-01-01    19    22    16 ""      
#>  2 2009-01-02    20    21    19 19      
#>  3 2009-01-03    22    21    16 19/20   
#>  4 2009-01-04    20    20    17 19/20/22
#>  5 2009-01-05    20    19    17 19/20/22
#>  6 2009-01-06    22    24    13 19/20/22
#>  7 2009-01-07    20    21    23 19/20/22
#>  8 2009-01-08    19    16    21 19/20/22
#>  9 2009-01-09    19    21    15 19/20/22
#> 10 2009-01-10    20    19    25 19/20/22
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on *"I'd like to turn this into a query to check whether the value for X in a given row appeared in the X column for any earlier dates"*, I think you simply need whether `X` is duplicated or not. If that's right, you can do -

```
stocks$prev_X <- duplicated(stocks$X)

# A tibble: 10 x 5
   time           X     Y     Z prev_X
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> 
 1 2009-01-01    20    20    26 FALSE 
 2 2009-01-02    20    21    21 TRUE  
 3 2009-01-03    23    20    20 FALSE 
 4 2009-01-04    21    20    24 FALSE 
 5 2009-01-05    18    19    13 FALSE 
 6 2009-01-06    21    20    16 TRUE  
 7 2009-01-07    20    23    20 TRUE  
 8 2009-01-08    18    21    19 TRUE  
 9 2009-01-09    19    22    23 FALSE 
10 2009-01-10    20    21    22 TRUE
```

Comment: How come it implicitly does this rowwise()? Based on the syntax, I would expect row 1 to come as true.

Comment: @Cauder `duplicated()` does not mark the first occurrence of any value.